# Using Angular with no template page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-templates

I have some routes with some views that use my index.html as template. On a specific view (for instance login page) I don't want to use index.html as template. How to do this with Angular:

```
My routes:
.when('/user/:id/update',{
      templateUrl: 'views/updateUser.html',
      controller:  'updateUserCtrl'
  })
  .when('/role', {
    templateUrl: 'views/role.html',
    controller: 'RoleCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    controller: 'RoleCtrl' //Here I want a page withou template
  })
```

I already tried use ui-route like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view/>',
    url: '/contacts'
})
.state('contacts.list', {
    // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
    url: '/list'
})
.state('contacts.detail', {
    // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    url: '/detail'
})
```

In Both cases my pages always inherit from my index.html.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What would be the point of routing to a page but not showing anything to the user? If you really had to, you could just route to a blank html template, but I don't see the point in i.

Comment: Do you maybe want to just have an empty body in your index.html and have one 'main' template that has all your current html with other routes as children, but with `/login` having a different main template?

Comment: Hi, my index.html have a template for almost of my pages, but some pages are totally different and I don't want to use index.html as template, I would like to have another to use on these pages that are different.
Another case is the login page. My login page is just a form to user sign up or click to register, I don't have header, footer, side menu and so on.

Comment: Hi @JasonGoemaat is somethink like this.
My index.html has all my structure like header, menu, footer, js and css imports, but at /login I want just a simple page without all of this stuffs, for instance an empty page with a simple form

Answer (score 0):

with ui-router at least you can do abstract: true to set the route to no template and stack controllers onto views for separated behavior.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

otherwise, with vanilla angularjs, theoretically you could just do template : "" if you wanted to load a controller with no template.
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/15/Routing-to-a-Controller-with-no-View-in-Angular

Comment: Hi,
Really thanks for your help, I tried to do this but it's not working, I don't know if I'm doing write.
I think what I'm trying to do is quite simple, and almost all projects have this scenario. Could you help me with a simple example?

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question. on your index.html, you have some elements that surround the ng-view in which your templates are being injected. You don't want those elements at all for your logged in page?

Comment: I think in that instance, you'll need a separate index page - like loggedInIndex.html which would have the markup you wanted and then, within your router, you'd do templateUrl : "views/loggedInIndex.html"

Comment: see jason goemaat's answer

Comment: I followed this documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views and them I did this:

    $stateProvider
      .state('contacts', {
       abstract: true,
      template: '<ui-view/>',
      url: '/contacts'
})
 .state('contacts.list', {
    // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
    url: '/list'
})
But even after this my contacts.list.html is inheriting from my index.html.

Someone has any idea? Just to known I'm using yeoman with angular-generate project

Comment: Hi @iwoodruff, that's it. That's what you said.

Comment: if uiRouter fixed your problem, would you mark my response as having answered your question? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is not recommended, because your browser reloaded all content of your app and it breaks all concept of a Single Page Application.

One of approaches is using `ng-view`/`ui-view` in your template (html file) and `$location` in your service/controller to replace the url address if user authentication was ok.

Take a look in this plnkr with two examples that work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vPyH5lwbwYCMx6RCnVb0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For the views where you do not want index.html's base template (header, footer, etc) to appear - you can use a div that overlays the entire page (in that component's html and css).